# Check Dates in Trigger

Tags: sql, database, triggers

I have two tabs (ticket, race), I want to check date inside the tab ticket and also in race tab, the ticket’s date needs to be earlier than date of the race.
I have a problem on my trigger when I try to put a new ticket inside, he gives me back an error. (#1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 rows)

```
DELIMITER |
CREATE TRIGGER ControllaBiglietto
BEFORE INSERT ON Biglietto
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (SELECT Gara.Giorno FROM Gara, Biglietto WHERE 
Biglietto.Gara=Gara.Nome)>new.DataEmissione THEN
INSERT INTO Biglietto VALUES (new.Codice, new.Prezzo, NULL, 
new.Spettatore, new.Gara, new.Rivenditore);
ELSE 
INSERT INTO Biglietto VALUES (new.Codice, new.Prezzo, 
new.DataEmissione,new.Spettatore, new.Gara, new.Rivenditore); 
END IF ;
END
```

Comment: How many rows does `(SELECT Gara.Giorno FROM Gara, Biglietto WHERE 
Biglietto.Gara=Gara.Nome)` return? Since the `WHERE` clause is rather a hidden `ON` clause (consider using explicit `JOIN`s) I suspect it's more than one row. Change it to only result in one row.

Comment: This query returns a lot of rows and this is a problem because i want to check between dates of the tickets and the dates of the race.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and triggers are highly vendor specific

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason to do a `join`.  I think you want:

```
IF (SELECT Gara.Giorno
    FROM Gara
    WHERE new.Gara = Gara.Nome
   ) > new.DataEmissione THEN
    INSERT INTO Biglietto ( . . .)
        VALUES (new.Codice, new.Prezzo, NULL, new.Spettatore, new.Gara, new.Rivenditore);
ELSE 
    INSERT INTO Biglietto ( . . . )
        VALUES (new.Codice, new.Prezzo, new.DataEmissione,new.Spettatore, new.Gara, new.Rivenditore); 
END IF ;
```

When you use `INSERT`, you should also list all the columns being inserted.  It is particularly important to learn how to write SQL well if you are learning the language.

Comment: I just need to modify the dates in Biglietto with NULL if that date is greater than Gara.Giorno